# Не грузятся данные из БД H2 с помощью Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jpa, h2

Пробую выгрузить все данные из БД H2  с помощью Spring JPA , после перехода по ссылке  http://localhost:8080/greeting    на выходе получаются пустые значения. Как сделать так, чтобы получить все данные из таблицы?

**Контроллер:**

```
package RestExample.MainPack.Controller;

import RestExample.MainPack.model.salespointdo;
import RestExample.MainPack.repos.SalesPointRepos;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    SalesPointRepos salesPointRepos;


    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    @ResponseBody
    public String greeting() {


        salespointdo ss= new salespointdo();

        Iterable<salespointdo> allSP=salesPointRepos.findAll();

        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

        allSP.forEach(sp->sb.append(sp+"<br>"));


        return  allSP.toString();
    }
}
```

**Entity:**

```
    package RestExample.MainPack.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "salespointdo")
public class salespointdo {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Long id;

 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;

 @Column(name = "city")
 private String city;

 @Column(name = "address")
 private String address;

    public salespointdo() {
    }

    public Long getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "City: "+getCity()+" "+"Address: "+getAddress();
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
    package RestExample.MainPack.repos;

import RestExample.MainPack.model.salespointdo;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface SalesPointRepos extends CrudRepository<salespointdo,Long> {



}
```

**SpringBoot:**

```
package RestExample.MainPack;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;



@SpringBootApplication
public class StartRest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StartRest.class, args);



    }
}
```

**application.properties**:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true



spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./SalesPoint
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.platform=h2



spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Скрин из базы данных]

Выше привел логи  из  SpringBoot и  таблицу H2  и результат выполнения

[image: результат]

Comment: Тоесть на основе класа(сущности) создалась таблица в БД? и SELECT ничего не возвращает?

Comment: @Jacson750 Нет,  в БД заранее были введены значения. И в контроллере вызывается  метод findAll() из репозитория , которая должна вернуть эти данные из таблицы

Comment: Таблица создавалась вручную или автоматически?

Comment: @Jacson750 таблица и  данные в таблице вручную были заведены

Comment: Удалите таблицу или создайте новую тестовую сущность. Таблицу на основе сущности сгенерит автоматически. Если нет тогда дело в конфигах

Comment: обновил ответ. Попробуй так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

application.properties

```
# To See H2 Console in Browser:
# http://localhost:8080/h2-console
# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
#
## ===============================#
## DB                             #
## ===============================#
#
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdatabase
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

Попробуй так

Comment: тоже самое возращает , что и на последнем скриншоте ( пустые квадратные скобки)  Сейчас попробую удалить таблицу

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan новую сущность создал для теста?

Comment: Пока нет, создаю. Но попробовал удалить таблицу, чтобы программа сама создала автоматически- ничего не вышло, проверил в базе таблицы нет.

Comment: тогда дело в конфигах. Вопрос:  работа вся происходит локально (на одном устойстве)?

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan из-за конфигов проект просто "не видел"  вашу БД

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103930/discussion-between-jackson750-and-vaagn-akopyan).

Comment: к сожалению из-за настроек безопасности не могу в чате общаться.   Напишите сюда в чем именно проблема была в конфиге?

Comment: у тебя строка spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./SalesPoint где указано к какому файлу идет коннект (SalesPoint) а файла то такого нет. У меня в примере spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdatabase где mem єто БД in memory, create произойдет при запуске

Comment: Я подозревал очень на эту строку, но не мог понять в чем загвостка.  При создании БД  система сама выбрала такой синтаксис.  А как правильно должна была выглядеть это строка?  Если  делать как ты  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdatabase  , то это вариант, когда БД создается при запуске программы и до ее завершения. Но я хотел, чтобы БД была постоянной, чтобы записи хранились там и после завершения программы.